# Serialize a Java Object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Let me know the best way to serialize my Java object Download.  This is a class generated from a java wsimport tool from a WSDL.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Download", propOrder = {
    "Response",
    "VendorInformation",
    "DownloadItem",
    "DownloadCommentItem",
    "DownloadIntercomItem"
})

public class Download 
{

    @XmlElement(name = "Response")
    protected ResponseMessageManagementType Response;
    @XmlElement(name = "VendorInformation")
    protected DownloadVendorInformation VendorInformation;
    @XmlElement(name = "DownloadItem")
    protected List<DownloadDownloadItem> DownloadItem;
    @XmlElement(name = "DownloadCommentItem")
    protected ArrayOfDownloadDldComment DownloadCommentItem;
    @XmlElement(name = "DownloadIntercomItem")
    protected ArrayOfDownloadDldIntercom DownloadIntercomItem;

    .........................
}
```

The java classes generated from the tool do not have any serlization implementation.
And I want to serialize the Download class following this kind of format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Download xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns="HTTP://xyz.abc.Com//Vendor/DownloadWSE.xsd">
  <Response>
   .....
  </Response>

  <VendorInformation>
   ...............
  </VendorInformation>

  <DownloadItem>
    <DownloadDownloadItem>
       .......
    </DownloadDownloadItem>
    <DownloadDownloadItem>
       .......
    </DownloadDownloadItem>
    <DownloadDownloadItem>
       .......
    </DownloadDownloadItem>
  </DownloadItem>
  <DownloadCommentItem>
    ........
  </DownloadCommentItem>
  <DownloadIntercomItem>
    ........
  </DownloadIntercomItem>
</Download>
```

You can see the mapping between XmlElementName and the content of the XML string.
I am at loss on how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is JAXB, and to get your example working you need to supply root element and namespace information:

**Root Element**

When you marshal an object with JAXB it requires information about the root element.  One way to do this is to annotate your `Download` class with `@XmlRootElement`

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Download")
public class Download
```

If you cannot do that you will need to wrap your instance of `Download` in a `JAXBElement`:

```
Download download = new Download();
QName qname = new QName("HTTP://xyz.abc.Com//Vendor/DownloadWSE.xsd";
JAXBElement<Download> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement(qname, "Download"), Download.class, download);
```

**Namespace Qualification**

Also to get the namespace qualification you are after you can use the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation:

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace="HTTP://xyz.abc.Com//Vendor/DownloadWSE.xsd", 
    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package your.model.package.containing.download;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

**Demo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Download.class);

        Download download = new Download();
        QName qname = new QName("HTTP://xyz.abc.Com//Vendor/DownloadWSE.xsd";
        JAXBElement<Download> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement(qname, "Download"), Download.class, download);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, System.out);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes.  RootElement was missing from the class definition.

Answer (score 2):

This is [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/). You would need:

```
JAXBContext ctx = JAXBConetxt.newInstance(Download.class);
Marshaller m = ctx.createMarshaller();
m.marshal(downloadObject, out);
```

where `out` can be lots of things, including `OutputStream`, `Writer` and `File`. If you want to get it as a `String`, use a `StringWriter`